# 3D graphics don't work with Sis Mirage graphics chip

Tags: unity, hardware, video, 3d

I wanted to test Ubuntu 11.04 on my fujitsu siemens esprimo mobile v5535 laptop but on first boot i get the message: "Sorry, you don't have 3d support, install it for your graphic hardware to get Unity or please reboot and select 'Classic session' at startup."

I had Windows 7 on this laptop and all the visual effects worked just fine. Does anyone knows where can i get drivers that support 3D?

Comment: Confirming the details in the answers below, the graphics chip you have in your system do not have any Linux drivers which allow for the support of 3D graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This laptop uses a Sis MIrage 3 driver. There are no 3D linux drivers for it rigth now.

Comment: I found drivers for linux at http://www.sis.com/download/ but i don't know if they are 2D or 3D or how to use them.

Comment: 2D only, unless they have released a new driver.

Answer (score -1):

According to some quick research this laptop has a SiS Mirage 3+ Graphics chip.

Read here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9937432&postcount=5

You will need to download and install the driver manually; the graphics chip you have is not well supported in Linux.

[image: Forum post]

Comment: Sorry I hate to downvote a question as worked as yours, but this drivers is 2D only.

Comment: Ack. Missed that. :(